# How does the enumerator receive a block?

Tags: ruby, iterator

I have:

```
letters = %w(e d c b a)
```

In the following:

```
letters.group_by.each_with_index { |item, index| index % 3 }
#=> {0=>["e", "b"], 1=>["d", "a"], 2=>["c"]}
```

how can the enumerator returned by `group_by` know the block it will execute? Is the block received by `each_with_index` passed to the enumerator which it is based on?

In the following:

```
letters.each_with_index.group_by { |item, index| index % 3 }
#=> {0=>[["e", 0], ["b", 3]], 1=>[["d", 1], ["a", 4]], 2=>[["c", 2]]}
```

will the block be passed to the enumerator returned by `each_with_index`? If it will, how does `each_with_index` execute it?

In general:

1. How is a block retrieved by a method in an enumerator that doesn't directly receive the block?
2. Will a block be passed through an enumerator chain? Where will it be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some tricky stuff going on here, so that's probably why you're a little hazy on how it works. Enumerators are one of the most important things in Ruby, they're the backbone of the Enumerable system which is where Ruby really shines, but they're often used in ways where they're transparent, living in the shadows, so you rarely have to pay direct attention to them.

Looking more closely, step through this bit by bit:

```
letters.group_by
# => #<Enumerator: ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]:group_by>
```

Now this is an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html) instance. The `each_with_index` you chain on the end is actually an *Enumerator-specific* method:

```
letters.group_by.method(:each_with_index)
# => #<Method: Enumerator#each_with_index>
```

This is in contrast to your second approach:

```
letters.method(:each_with_index)
# => #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#each_with_index>
```

That one is Array's method which, conveniently, you can chain into a method like `group_by`.

So the story here is that `group_by` in chain mode actually provides special methods that have the effect of back-propagating your block to the `group_by` level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the second example, the `each_index_with` should also receive the effect of block to the `each_with_index` level?  how does it work?   If I want to figure out the specific details , where I can learn it? the ruby source code?

Comment: Some of these are implemented in Ruby, others in C, so the source code might be a little more difficult to understand if in C, but it is there. The second example `each_with_index` simply expands your array into an array of pairs, and `group_by` is not special-cased, so it works as usual, one enumerator simply feeding into the next, no back-propagation. In the first there's a special case `each_with_index` which operates not on the output of the Enumerator, but the Enumerator itself.

Comment: how to understand the `special case`? how do I know whether a case is a `special case` which I have never seen in textbook. Any way, in current state, I just want to know how to chain these enumerators correctly to achieve my goal. Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: What I mean by special case is `each_with_index` comes in two distinct flavours here. One is when called directly on the Array, the other when it's called on an Enumerator. They're not the same method, they just work in similar ways and share a method name.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and comment, it solves my confusion perfectly.